# Binding validation failed

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a very simple WCF program that writes data to an MSMQ, but I get this error

```
Binding validation failed because the binding's MsmqAuthenticationMode property is set to WindowsDomain but MSMQ is installed with Active Directory integration disabled. The channel factory or service host cannot be opened.
```

The config file I am using is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalNoSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalTransportSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingTransactionalTransportSecurity" exactlyOnce="true">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="MsmqService"
                address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MsmqService/MsmqService.svc"
                binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="MsmqBindingTransactionalTransportSecurity"
                contract="MsmqContract.IMsmqContract" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493239/wcf-in-iis-using-msmq-in-workgroup-mode

Comment: check the installed server features. Make sure "Directory Service Integration" is installed under Message Queueing